# Latest chrome cannot load some SVG images via SSL

Tags: google-chrome

Has anybody else noticed this with the latest version of Chrome?  I have a PayPal svg logo on a CDN and when loaded via SSL Chrome gives an error...

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

Here is the SSL link:  https://a87617f02a1007f51c8f-e1a64ff9a451d17ba5af147df976bbd6.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/paypal.svg

However it works when I open it via an non SSL connection, as seen here...

http://37d92313507f4ae3629c-e1a64ff9a451d17ba5af147df976bbd6.r14.cf2.rackcdn.com/paypal.svg

However the SSL link works in Safari and this issue wasn't here before the Chrome update that hit my computer.

And to make matters more confusing... some SVG files over SSL do work:

https://a87617f02a1007f51c8f-e1a64ff9a451d17ba5af147df976bbd6.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/stripe-credit-cards.svg

Thoughts?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe Content-Type header issue?

Comment: It is unknown what you consider the "latest version". I've running 52.0.2743.116 (which seems to be the latest) and have no problems with the SSL link.

Comment: This is weird... I was seeing this issue on my MacBook last night.  But this morning from my Mac desktop the SVG loads fine (MacBook still does not).  So must be something with Chrome on my Mac Book.